# Is there a way to get/save the DOM with Selenium?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dom, selenium

What I'm looking for is a method that works like "captureScreenshot(String path)", but instead of producing an image is saves the DOM as it currently is.
Note that the existing getBodyText() method is not enough.

Comment: This is one of the problems with the Selenium API - it's cross-platform, and that means it's very primitive, so things like DOM support are going to be limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
getHtmlSource()
```

It will save all the content as a string in a variable, and then you can parse the dom as you want.

Comment: getHtmlSource() is, unfortunately, a bit buggy AFAICT: http://clearspace.openqa.org/thread/22095?tstart=0

Comment: HtmlSource() is not DOM!